# Are my answers correct here with Taylor\Maclaurin series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to solve this & not sure if it is the right answers, the question is:

Given function f(x) is  $3$ times derivable at $0$, and the Maclaurin series of the function f(x) up to the order  $2$    is :
$f(x) = ax + bx^2 + R_2(x)$.

1. Does $f''(0)=b$?

My answer is no because $f''(0)=2b$, is that correct?

Given $a=1$, and -

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)}{x} & \text {if $x\ne0$} \\
1 & \text {if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$

Does $g'(0)=b$?

the answer is yes, does my answer is correct?

Comment: Your answers are correct, but they have to be justified..

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: Your answers are correct, but the tag "differential-equations" is rather out of place here.

Comment: Thank you guys, @user539887 sorry I made a mistake, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for the first one is right; however, I'm pretty sure the second one is false. Indeed, differentiability at $x_0$ implies $g$ is continuous at $x_0$. So I'll show $g$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Indeed, we shall compare $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)/x$ with $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 0$. If $g$ is continuous, they should agree.

As $f(x) = x + bx^2 + R_2(x)$, we see $\frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 + bx + R_2(x)/x$. By definition of Taylor Series, $R_2(x) = O(x^3)$, so we see $R_2(x)/x = O(x^2)$; in particular $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} R_2(x)/x = 0$. So $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 \neq 0$. So $g$ is not continuous at $x=0$, so it is not differentiable at $x=0$, so $g'(0)$ is undefined.